# How to use the result to compute the next result and then the next result after that?

Tags: python, function, loops, math, formula

I am trying to use the result of the formula to compute the next result and then the next result after that and so on and so fourth.

```
def waiting(element, start_waiting_time=0, service_time=1.2, interarrival=1,  default=0):
    if element == 1:
        return max((start_waiting_time + service_time - interarrival, 0))
    elif element == 0:
        return default

def waiting_time(elements, start_time=0):
    next_patient_waits = start_time
    for i in elements:
        next_patient_waits += waiting(i)
        print("{:.1f}".format(next_patient_waits))

elements = [1, 1, 1]
waiting_time(elements)
```

This code returns output:

```
# 0.2, 0.4, 0.6
```

I was expecting it to return output :

```
#0, 0.2, 0.4
```

I want to set the first waiting_time to 0 because the start_waiting_time is zero. I was hope the computer would compute:

```
#For 1st item in elements: waiting_time = 0
#For 2nd item in elements: waiting_time = (waiting time 1st element) + service_time - interarrival = 0 + 1.2 -1 = 0.2
#For 3rd item in elements: waiting_time = (waiting time 2nd element) + service_time - interarrival = 0.2 + 1.2 -1 = 0.4
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `waiting_time` is not a (mathematical) formula. Not a big issue but a structured approach for your algorithm might benefit from changing it to a real formula (which has a `return`). Your `waiting` is what I mean because it does have a `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply print the `next_patient_waits` before increasing it:

```
def waiting_time(elements, start_time=0):
    next_patient_waits = start_time
    for i in elements:
        print("{:.1f}".format(next_patient_waits))
        next_patient_waits += waiting(i)
```